# How to know my progress with others progress using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, compare, percentage

I have below table

```
CREATE TABLE run_progress
(
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   user varchar(255),
   progress numeric
)

INSERT INTO run_progress ( id, user, progress ) VALUES ( 1, 1, 100 )
INSERT INTO run_progress ( id, user, progress ) VALUES ( 2, 2, 90 )
INSERT INTO run_progress ( id, user, progress ) VALUES ( 3, 3, 60 )
INSERT INTO run_progress ( id, user, progress ) VALUES ( 4, 4, 10 )
```

I want to know user:4 progress compare to rest of the users in the table.
User:4 made a 10% progress, is it possible to know his progress compare to others progress in the table in a global view point?
this is to know how far he is behind or forward compare to the rest of the users.

thank you.

Comment: Don't you get it with `Select user, progress from run_progress` ?

Comment: @sri User:4 completion progress is 10% but how to know his ranking ?

Comment: @Eric . . . Please show the results you want.  Your description is ambiguous.

Comment: @GordonLinoff how to know user:4 rank. Because he completed only 10% his rank should be 4. User:2 rank should be 90 and user:1 rank should be 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate and compare summary statistics in one row:

```
select max(progress) filter (where id = 4) as user_4,
       min(progress) filter (where id <> 4) as min_other_users,
       max(progress) filter (where id <> 4) as max_other_users,
       avg(progress) filter (where id <> 4) as avg_other_users
from run_progress p
```

Comment: this gives 95% for user:1. But actually user:1 has completed the 100% so it should be 100%. I dont think this query works for me.

Comment: @Eric . . . Can you set up a db fiddle?  I see no way that this can return 95% for user 1.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a window sum fit your need?

```
select *
from (
    select 
        p.*, 
        avg(progress) filter(where id <> 4) over() avg_progress_of_other_users
    from run_progress p
) p
where id = 4
```

If you want this for all users at once (not only for one specific user), then a lateral join is a better fit:

```
select p.*, a.*
from run_progress p
left join lateral (
    select avg(p1.progress) avg_progress_of_other_users
    from run_progress p1    
    where p1.id <> p.id
) a on true
```

Comment: for any user this query gives me 66.6666666666667, i dont think its correct